# Plotting phase plane in Matlab for SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matlab

I want to plot the phase plane of the SIR model,

[image]
I used the method describe in [here](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/08/09/phase-portraits-of-a-system-of-odes/)

This is the code that I wrote,

```
function SIREquilibrium()
S0=0.8;
I0=0.2;
R=1-S0-I0;
beta=1;
gamma=1/10;
mu=5e-4;

f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2);gamma*y(2)-mu*y(3)];

y1=linspace(0,1,20);
y2=linspace(0,1,20);
[x,y]=meshgrid(y1,y2);
u=zeros(size(x));
v=zeros(size(y));
t=0;
for i=1:numel(x)
    Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);
    u(i)=Yprime(1);
    v(i)=Yprime(2);
end
quiver(x,y,u,v,'r')
```

But I get an error as

```
index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in SIREquilibrium>@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2);gamma*y(2)-mu*y(3)] (line 16)
f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2);gamma*y(2)-mu*y(3)];

Error in SIREquilibrium (line 25)
    Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);
```

I infact do not understand what `Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);` does in [this](http://matlab.cheme.cmu.edu/2011/08/09/phase-portraits-of-a-system-of-odes/)

Can someone please tell me how I can plot the phase plane of this SIR model

After making the changes to the code as `f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2)];`
 the phase plane I get is
[image]

But, I think it should be
[image]

Can you suggest me what I am doing wrong to get a phase plane like that.

I changed the linspace to see why the spiraling in behavior couldn't be seen. And this is the phase plot that I get.
[image]

```
function SIREquilibrium()
if nargin==0
   S0=0.8;
   I0=0.2;
   beta=0.3;
   gamma=1/10;
   mu=5e-5;
end


f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2)];

y1=linspace(0,1,20);
y2=linspace(0,1,20);
[x,y]=meshgrid(y1,y2);
u=zeros(size(x));
v=zeros(size(y));
t=0;
for i=1:numel(x)

    Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);
    Yprime=Yprime/norm(Yprime);
    u(i)=Yprime(1);
    v(i)=Yprime(2);

end
quiver(x,y,u,v,'r')
axis tight equal
hold on

for y10=[0:0.2:1]
    for y20=[0:0.2:1]
    options=odeset('MaxStep',0.1);
    [ts,ys]=ode45(f,[0,4000],[y10,y20],options);
    plot(ys(:,1),ys(:,2))
    end
end
hold off
```

Comment: Add a test `if x(i) + y(i) < 1` inside your for loop and follow Ian's suggestion to normalize with `Yprime = Yprime / norm(Yprime);`.  It will look better.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I normalized and used the if condition. But still I can't see it spiraling towards the equilibrium point. Near the equilibrium point I can't see the behavior correctly. But in the rest of the field it seems to have the correct behavior.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are using $R_0 = \beta/\gamma = 10$ instead of $3$ as in the picture.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi changing R0 doesn't make any difference

Comment: It does for me.  The quiver plot is useful at the larger scale, but at some point you may want to draw some real trajectories.  Use `[0,4000]` for your time span , and `[S0;I0]` for your initial conditions.  Do you know how to set options for `ode45` with `odeset`?  You need to limit the maximum time step with something like `options = odeset('MaxStep', 0.1);`

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi I changed as you suggested. But even for R0=3, still near the x axis it doesn't show the behaviour as spiraling in. Is it a issue with the chosen size of the meshgrid. But S,I can only be between (0,1)

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi I changed the linspace to see what happens beyond 0, 1 and I I have included that phase plane in the post. With the behaviour around x axis I don't see how it can spiral in

Comment: The trajectories take very sharp turns once they get very close to the $x$ axis.  I've seen trajectories spiral with your exact `f` and the `ode45` settings I outlined above.  They are just less rounded than in the figure you posted.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi I changed R0 so that it equals 3. I have normalized use the ode 45 options that you suggested. I have included my code after these changes in the post. Could you please go through it and see what I am doing wrong that I can't see the spiraling in behaviour

Comment: At first glance, you need to make sure that the initial values `y10` and `y20` add up to 1 if you want to be close to that figure.

Comment: Incidentally, increasing $\mu$ by an order of magnitude ($5\cdot10^{-3}$) makes the plots look much more like the figure you posted.  Not identical, but remarkably similar.  I think the only significant difference between my code and yours is that I have a single loop `for y10 = [0.99, 0.8:-0.2:0.2]` and then set the initial conditions to `[y10; 1-y10]`.  Should I now take down my "answer?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed in a vector of length 2 into the second argument of f and then asked for its third element in the evaluation of f. You can't do that.

Given the rest of the code, my guess would be that you don't actually care about $R$ (because you're using quiver, which will give a 2D phase portrait, not quiver3). So you can just delete that last row of f (the one representing $\frac{dR}{dt}$), and then your code will work. That is, you would replace

```
f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2);gamma*y(2)-mu*y(3)];
```

with

```
f=@(t,y)[mu-beta*y(1)*y(2)-mu*y(1);beta*y(1)*y(2)-gamma*y(2)-mu*y(2)];
```

Note that this makes some sense because only $\frac{dR}{dt}$ involves $R$. You also are not really throwing away information because in your case the relation $S+I+R=1$ is preserved by the dynamics.

The alternative would be to make an actual 3D phase portrait, in which case you would need to pass in a value for R to f in your loop, with something like:

```
Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i);z(i)])
```

and then use quiver3 at the end. In this case you could still initialize everything using meshgrid; in such a case x,y,z will be tensors of order 3 (i.e. "matrices" depending on three indices).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Since S+I+R=1, can I not consider ${dR\over dt}$  and use only the other two equations. The 3d quiver works but I want to see the phase plane between `S` and `I`. Also, since all, S,I,R lie in (0,1) I choose `linspace(0,1,20);`. How to decide what values to be chosen for linspace. In plotting phase plane should I first calculate the equilibrium point, and then use linspace such that it includes this equilibrium point.

Comment: @clarkson So I didn't notice the "birth" term $\mu$ in $\frac{dS}{dt}$. With that there you are right that you have a conservation law for the total population so it makes sense to ignore $R$ altogether. In this case you should just delete the third row in the definition of f and then leave it be. Your portrait does not really need to explicitly include the equilibrium; the picture will fairly clearly show it anyway provided your grid is fine enough.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the phase plane I get. But it seems not to be correct. It would be a great help if you an show me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: @clarkson Your figure looks qualitatively correct but it is really hard to see the small vectors towards the lower corner. You can fix that by normalizing the derivative vectors, so that you show only the direction and not the speed.

Comment: How can I draw the lines on the phase plane. With that I think I'd be able to see it better what happens.I found that I could use `quiver(x,y,u,v,'r')
figure(gcf)
axis tight equal
hold on
for y20=[0:0.1:1]
    [ts,ys]=ode45(f,[0,100],[1,y20]);
    plot(ys(:,1),ys(:,2))
end
hold off` to draw lines on the phase plane. However, I do not understand  what values should be chosen for `y20` and in ode45, whether it is [1,y20]

Comment: @clarkson For the lines that's another matter entirely, you would need to solve the ODE for various initial conditions to get those. You might want to google pplane, it can do all this sort of stuff quite easily.

Comment: That said, if you normalize the vector u,v it should be easy enough to see what's going on...

Comment: @Ian In the code where direction fields are drawn, `t=0;
for i=1:numel(x)

    Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);
    Yprime=Yprime/norm(Yprime);
    u(i)=Yprime(1);
    v(i)=Yprime(2);

end` why is t=0 chosen specifically? Is it because we should know the initial conditions? Say I have a system of 5 ODEs and I am using phase analysis to see the behaviour of only two of those variables. Then for the line `Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i)]);` should I use initial conditions for the other 3 variables `Yprime=f(t,[x(i);y(i);5,0,100])`, so that I am drawing the direction fields for the first two ODEs

Comment: @sam_rox Since this problem is autonomous the choice of the is rather arbitrary. We keep a time argument so as to match with the conventions of Matlab's ode solvers.

Comment: @sam_rox I meant to say "the choice of the value of $t$".